# Can BindingResult or FieldErrors or GlobalErrors ever be null in my case?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception

I have an error  handler like below

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Error> methodArgumentNotValidHandler(final MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    final List<String> errors = e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(error -> error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    e.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors().stream()
            .forEach(error -> errors.add(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage()));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(new Error(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, errors), HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}
```

I was wondering though if BindingResult or FieldErrors from .getFieldErrors or GlobalErrors from getGlobalErrors could ever turn out to be null, because that would be very bad

Comment: it would never be null.

Comment: Upvoted for quick reply thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be. Writing a failure case for this in Integration testing should clear your doubt.

The exception handler is invoked for `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. So, it should have some field error. 
But for a cleaner code, I would recommend to check `hasFieldErrors()` if the exception handler handles some other exception alongside `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

Comment: Okay thanks. By a check you mean a null check correct?

Comment: no, `hasFieldErrors()` return a boolean, do your operation if it returns `true`

Comment: No. `e.getBindingResult().hasFieldErrors()` before streaming. FieldErrors wount be null. Instead would be an empty list. So null check wont be required I hope.

Answer (score 0):

to get the error message use this code in your Controller:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
...

FieldError error = bindingResult.getFieldError("fieldName");
String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(error, Locale.getDefault());
```